# Is it possible to use 2 document.ready function in razor view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view

I'm working in `Asp.net MVC3`. I'm using `jquery` in `razor` view. Is it possible to use 2 `document.ready(function(){});` in the same view page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to use more than 1 document.ready calls within the same HTML document. jQuery will aggregate them into a single javascript code that will be invoked when the DOM is ready.